# JPQL Query - java.lang.String cannot be cast to model.xxx

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql

ACTUAL FULL ERROR

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to model.Persone
```

--

Hi al, I'm very new to JPQL and I'm  trying to write a quite simple JPQL Query without luck.

I have a database table named persone with the a String nome column.

The query I'd like to translate is `SELECT Nome FROM persone`

--

Here's the entity

```
@Entity
public class Persone implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_persona")
    private int idPersona;

    private String cognome;

    private Timestamp data_nascita;

    @Column(name="nome")
    private String nome;
}
```

--

This is a snippet of the query execution method. I tried to modify it setting the return (and everything else) to String instead of List, but then I can't manage to get the right method instead of getResultList().

```
public static List<Persone> selectAllPersone(){
    Query selectAll = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Persone p");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Persone> list = selectAll.getResultList();
    return list;
}
```

--

And here's me failing at coding

```
Query selectAll = em.createQuery("SELECT p.nome FROM Persone p");
```

What could this error be due to?

Comment: please write the actual code snippet you have tried that is giving you the error and not the original one that is working... so we can probably see what you did wrong and help

Comment: I found out the solution by myself, thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort it out and have it work for me.
I just created a new method which returns a `List<String>` and it went fine.

```
public static List<String> selectNome(){
    Query selectAll = em.createQuery("SELECT p.nome FROM Persone p");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String> qnome = selectAll.getResultList();
    return qnome;
}
```

Thank you guys for your help :)

Comment: Note: If you select more than one element from Person, you'll get an `Object[]`. So `SELECT p.nome, p.id FROM Personne p` will return an `Object[2]`.

Comment: yeah was trying to see this very line List<String> qnome = selectAll.getResultList(); you probably had its return as a simple String without List

Answer (score 4):

You are selecting the name (`p.nome`) which is a string, so you'll get a string back.

If you want a whole person to be returned, select the whole person (`SELECT p FROM Personne p`).

Comment: I already managed to select the whole person and now my aim was to select one column only.

I'll edit adding a brief table description

Comment: You are selecting one column only, but it's a `String`, not a `Person`. Simply do not cast it to person and it will work. If you want a `Person` with only the name, manually construct it and set the name, or, if you have a constructor that takes a String parameter for name, you can use `SELECT NEW Persone(p.nome) FROM Persone P`.

Comment: You're suggesting to not to cast it to person.
I don't remember casting anything, is it in the snippets I provided?

Comment: provide some more information, possibly your code snippet where you execute your query

Comment: You're getting a class cast exception, there must be a cast somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Query selectAll = em.createQuery("SELECT p.nome FROM Persone p");
```

As you code shows you are selecting only string from query not all person object
Following query will return person object

```
Query selectAll = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Persone p");
  List<Persone> list = selectAll.getResultList();
```

If you want to select only name from person.A name is string type and it will return `List<String>`

```
Query selectAll = em.createQuery("SELECT p.nome FROM Persone p");
List<String> result = selectAll.getResultList();
```